# Which encryption algorithm to use for password-protecting data?

Tags: c#, cryptography

I am currently thinking of something to do as my final project for my C# class. The thing that came up to my mind was a password-protected data storing application which would require a password to access data stored in a binary file.

The problem is that I am not sure which encryption to use if I would decide to do this project.

What encryption would fit best this scenario? Which encryption is the best?

Just little more info what I have planned.

First, user must specify the user name/password information to save the data. Data would be saved in binary file which later should be able to view after login information are correct.

Comment: I purged all the comments and I'm two minds about doing the same to many/most/all of the answers as well. If you *please read the question*, then you'll notice that what he's asking how to implement is a LastPass-like system. **All the comments and answers about "never do this, always hash" is plain off base**. I would be very upset if LastPass suddenly decided that I cannot retrieve any of the passwords from their system because someone who didn't read the specification decided to hash everything.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: if you took the time to read the initial, unedited question, you would have realized why most answers were heading in that direction. "A password storing application" is ambiguous in that sense, and I still feel that our answers contributed to OP's question. And while the answers *were* "plain off base" at the time you added *your* comment, comments that you've deleted allowed the OP to get to the point to understand the problem with her/his question and modify it, IMHO. But I guess we can still add new answers to the updated question anyway.

Comment: This question just seems to say he wants to make an application which requires authentication before it will show you the contents of a binary file. So it is implied that the file should be encrypted and once a user has logged in they can view the contents, if this isnt the case the question should be changed to closer reflect what the actual question is.

Comment: I *did* read the edit history, the initial edit said "password storing application".

Comment: "Password-protected data storing application" still implies that it is an application which is password protected, which stores data. Which would make both current answers applicable, however they are just being marked down even though they both contain useful information related to the question in its current state.

Comment: @Lasse: that's right. To quote the original question: *[program] would use encrypted password in binary file*. Which led three or four people, including myself, to think that it's supposed to store an **encrypted password in a binary file**. I, for instance, would be upset if LastPass stored my master password using a reversible algorithm. It doesn't, and that's what should be clear to OP.

Comment: @Grofit: This is exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Groo: I am just trying to come up with a ahead plan of how to do this. "would use encrypted password in binary file" meant that, as I first thought, encrypt data in the binary file so, if stolen/hacked or whatever, data could not be retrieved with out knowing right user name/login information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should go with [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) in [CTR mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Counter_.28CTR.29).

A C# implementation of Rijndael (the underlying cipher of AES) can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndael.aspx).

There is probably not such a thing as the **best** encryption algorithm, but it is what everybody else is using right know.

**To clarify further:**

This is how encryption works:

```
Plaintext -> [encryption] -> Ciphertext -> [decryption] -> Plaintext
```

This is what you would have to use for a password manager.

This is how hashing works:

```
Message -> [hashing] -> Hash -> [???] -> Message
```

You can (and should) use hashing algorithms to store (hashed) passwords in a database for authentication purposes (e.g. log into a website). To do so, you use a salt or a key-based message authentication code.

Instead of "dehashing" the hash stored in the database, you just hash the user input and verify if it matches. This does **not** work for an application like a password manager.

With a cryptographically secure hashing function (like [SHA-512](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2)), it is currently impossible to "dehash", i.e., even if you know the hash, you cannot retrieve the message.

Comment: @Dennis: So hashing in my situation is out of the question. Great, because this brought me a great amount of confusion. Your encryption scenario seems like like it is what I need. +1. I will look up on topic of AES and CTR.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is an answer to your question, but alot of systems that store usernames and passwords tend to just hash the passwords, so you never actually store the users password, just the one way hashed version of it. That way when they try to login again you just hash the  password and compare it to the existing one.

MD5 is the simplest one, but I believe SHA256/512 is one of the better ones to use, this is a one way hashing algorithm though, and may not be applicable to your situation if you need to be able to ever gain access to the plain text version of their passwords. Usually this isnt an issue as you can just get them to change their passwords and a user never really needs to see their password in plain text.

If you cannot use one way hashing, then just use blowfish or some other simple two way encryption algorithm. The internet is full of different .net encryption providers. If it is homework I dont think it will really matter, as long as you can show a working knowledge of why and when you would use encryption you should get marks.